# search data between two date give in c# and using msAcc

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, c#-2.0

the Following query give me a error how i can correct it ....

```
select * from invoice_master where  modify_date between '11/3/2013 5:54:55 PM' 
and '12/30/2013 5:54:55 PM';

String qu = "select * from invoice_master where  modify_date between '" + 
            dateTimePicker1.Value + "' and '" + dateTimePicker2.Value + "' ;";

DataTable d = new DataTable();

d = ds.get_date_Table(qu);

dataGridView1.DataSource = d;
dataGridView1.Show();

public DataTable get_date_Table(String query)
{
    OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(connection);
    OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(query, con);


    DataTable dt = new DataTable();

    try
    {
        adapter.Fill(dt);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }

    return dt;
}
```

Comment: What error? Also, I see SQL, not C#.

Comment: Where is `c#-3.0` and `c#-5.0` tags?

Comment: it give me the Errow   Data type mismatch in criteria expression.

Comment: @user2991031 You should post the full code you're using, not a random fragment. Currently we have no idea how you're executing your query.

Comment: String qu = "select * from invoice_master where  modify_date between '" + dateTimePicker1.Value + "' and '" + dateTimePicker2.Value + "' ;";

                    DataTable d = new DataTable();

                    d = ds.get_date_Table(qu);

                    dataGridView1.DataSource = d;
                    dataGridView1.Show();

Comment: We need to see the columns of your database table and for `dataGridView1`. It is not recommended to do `select *` queries, it is better to explicitly name each column you need.

Comment: *Possibly* a date format issue. You may need to change dates from 12/30/2013 to 30/12/2013 **OR** configure things so that it accepts dates as MM/DD/YYYY

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As always this kind of problem is due to string concatanation habits.
You should always use a parameterized query and leave the burden to correctly quote your parameters to the database engine code

```
String qu = "select * from invoice_master where  modify_date between ? and ?" + 
using(OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(connection))
using(OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(query, con))
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    adapter.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p1", dateTimePicker1.Value)
    adapter.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p2", dateTimePicker2.Value)
    adapter.Fill(dt);
}
```

In this way, whatever character is needed to enclose a date value (by the way with `MSAccess` it is the `#` symbol, but other database could have different requirements) it is added by the framework code that knows better than you and me how to pass a datetime value to the database engine.

Comment: Only because you are a new user I wish to remember you that if you find an answer helpful it is a good practice on this site accept the answer - [See help here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)